# How to reuse the query on a node page?

Tags: views, search, paging

I have a Views page which is a search page based on a Search API index containing a few filters. The results are rendered entities. When clicking one of the entities, I wonder if it is possible reuse the views query on that node page.

Say I only have 23 results by using certain filtering. When I click on one of the results, I want to *scroll* through the other 22 by using a pager. I have provided images of a non Drupal site that has what I want to achieve.

Possible solutions I can think of are as my title describes. Or create another similar view which only renders 1 entity which is used when clicking on one of the entities from the search results page. I would very much like to hear your input on this.

[image: View settings]

[image: Non Drupal site search results and detail page]

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same view, so not the node page, using a different (page-)display.

> You just change the pager to 1 per site and pass the page (querystring
>   argument for the pager) to this next view, where you show the entity
>   in a different view mode (maybe full).

For this you need to alter the node links in the first view. This could be done in [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x). Like:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'NAMEOFTHEVIEW') {
    foreach($view->result as $r => $result) {
      $view->result[$r]->desired_field[][] = 'path/to/view?page=' . $r;
    }
  }
}
```

This code won't run, it's kind of a hint. You need to debug yourself ;)